# MVC Template is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

[image: img]

I am not getting MVC template while creating a new web project.

Comment: Hint: the extra information on the right hand side lists the different types of project you can create - @Nikhil. Patel's answer is what you're looking for. On the next screen, when you click "OK" you will be given the choice of which type of WebApp you want to create :)

Answer (score 1):

You find it in a next tab just click **ok** and go forward.